# new JsonResult() in async API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm wondering if I should make this API a non-async or somehow get await in the method body:

```
[Route("identity")]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync() => new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
}
```

I'm not able to find a ready to use solution where `JsonResult` can return awaited. Any help, remove async, or just ignore the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the async method lacks 'await' operators it will run synchronously, just as the warning says. There is no gain making it asynchronous.

To remove this warning you could make this method synchronous:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() => new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
```

Comment: I knew this one. But I'm infected by "EveryThingHasToBeAsync" virus right now...

Comment: @HassanGulzar Then you might want to get rid of the virus :) Using `async` keyword without `await` in body means the method is wrapped sync. If you figure out there is no possible to use `await`, then it is a good indication that the method should not be async.